# Output URL from custom registration field woocomerce/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a site for members only, on the registration page I need to put an input to upload files so far everything is ok, but the problem is that I need the uploaded file to appear in `wp-admin` in the user menu as a link download button or download button so that administrators can validate the uploaded file.

In the [wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) there is a `get_the_author_meta()` function and I am using this function to show the value of the file in the user profile, but it just returns the file `ID` and I would like to return the `URL` so that I can link the url to download.

here my code:

Custom Input to register form

```
// Add file input to register form
function add_woo_account_registration_fields() {
    
   ?>
    
   <p class="form-row" id="image_files">

      <label for="image_files" class="">Image (JPG, PNG, PDF)</label>

      <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
         <input type='file' name='image_files' accept='image/*,.pdf'>
      </span>

   </p>
    
   <?php
       
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_woo_account_registration_fields' );
```

Validade new custom field

```
// 2. Validate new field
function validate_woo_account_registration_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {
   if ( isset( $_POST['image_files'] ) && empty( $_POST['image_files'] ) ) {
      $errors->add( 'image_files_error', __( 'Please provide a valid image', 'woocommerce' ) );
   }
   return $errors;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'validate_woo_account_registration_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Save new field

```
// Save new field
function save_woo_account_registration_fields( $customer_id ) {
   if ( isset( $_FILES['image_files'] ) ) {
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
      require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
      $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image_files', 0 );
      if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'image_files', $_FILES['image_files'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );
      } else {
         update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'image_files', $attachment_id );
      }
   }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'save_woo_account_registration_fields', 1 );
```

Allow image upload

```
// Add enctype to form to allow image upload
function enctype_custom_registration_forms() {
   echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag', 'enctype_custom_registration_forms' );
```

Backend
Add Field to wp-admin

```
// Add field - admin
function add_user_files_field( $user ) {
   ?>
       <h3><?php _e('File','woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
       <table class="form-table">
           <tr>
               <th>
                  <label for="image_files"><?php _e( 'Files', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
               </th>
               <td>
                  
                  <!-- download file -->
                  <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'image_files', $user->ID ) ); ?>" download>Download</a>
                  
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
       <br/>
   <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_user_files_field', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_user_files_field', 10, 1 );
```

Save Field

```
// Save field - admin
function save_user_files_field( $user_id ) {
   if( ! empty($_POST['image_files']) ) {
       update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image_files', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['image_files'] ) );
   }
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_files_field', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_files_field', 10, 1 );
```

I know `get_the_author_meta( 'image_files', $user->ID )` will return me the file `ID` would there be another function to return the file `URL`?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

Comment: thanks a lot i did not know it is possible to use wp_get_attachment_url() on wp-admin it did the trick